# PHP OOP best practice to split low level class into two

Tags: object-oriented, php

What i got now is low level object that has bunch of methods and its difficult to navigate trough i want to break it down, however functions logically have same functionality just different implementation

```
class HTMLManipulator {

   function findElementById($html, $element) {
     ...
   }

   function setElementById($html, $element, $newValue) {
      ...
   }

   function findElementByIdDom(DOMDocument $dom, $element) {
     ...
   }

   function setElementByIdDom(DOMDocument $dom, $element, $newValue) {
      ...
   }


   ... few other unique functions...

   function TidyUpHTML($arg) {
      ...
   }

}
```

I use both function `findElementById`, `setElementById` and `findElementByIdDom`, `setElementByIdDom` in different parts of my application, so i cannot simply eliminate one, i wonder what approach i should take splitting this class ?

Should i create `interface` and two classes implementing it **vs** simply create parent class with full functionality and extend it overwriting key  functionality of parent class when needed?

```
class HTMLManipulator {

   function findElementById(DOMDocument $dom, $element) {
     ...
   }

   function setElementById(DOMDocument $dom, $element, $newValue) {
      ...
   }


   ... few other unique functions...

   function TidyUpHTML($arg) {
      ...
   }

}
```

.

```
//only overwrites this two methods from parent class inherits the rest
class HTMLManipulatorString extends HTMLManipulator {

   function findElementById($html, $element) {
     ...
   }

   function setElementById($html, $element, $newValue) {
      ...
   }

}
```

**page_one.php**

```
$obj = new HTMLManipulator();
$content = $obj->findElementById($dom, "pageFooter");
$obj->setElementById($dom, "pageContent", "Hello World!");          
$obj->TidyUpHTML($content);
...
```

**page_two.php**

```
$obj2 = new HTMLManipulatorString();
$menu = $obj->findElementById($html, "mainMenu");
$obj->setElementById($html, "pageFooter", "Copyright 2016");
$obj->TidyUpHTML($menu);
...
```

Is this code example bad OOP practice by any means and would you use this approach versus creating shared `interface` and two classes implementing it?